# What is OAuth and how does it secure REST API calls?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have mobile application REST API calls which hits to my server without any token or security mechanisam.

I want to secure my API calls. I am trying to understand what is OAuth and how it will secure my mobile app REST API calls which are hitting to my server?

Also I want to know in details about the below fields which are used in OAuth . From where I will get below fields.

```
Consumer Key
Consumer Secret
Token
Token Secret
Timestamp
Nonce
```

Comment: Read the oauth spec.

Comment: I read it but i didn't get it that's why i posted question here....

Comment: can u share the link with me for oauth and how this can be  implemented in mobile app to secure api??

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since most of providers use OAuth 2.0 and OAuth 1.0 has been deprecated by major providers, I will explain OAuth2.0

### What is OAuth?

OAuth is an open standard for authorization, commonly used as a way for Internet users to log in to third party websites using their Microsoft, Google, Facebook, Twitter, One Network etc. accounts without exposing their password.

you can implement your own OAuth server, here I am explaining about social auth. so the term OAuth here after refers to social auth with OAuth.

> In layman's terms, OAuth lets users login to your web service with  accounts(Facebook, Google etc).

### Terminology:

- **client**: The user of your API.
- **Resource Owner (api server):** Your API
- **Authorization Server (auth server):** Facebook/Google etc auth server.
- **Authorization grant:** the method by which you authorize a user. we are using Authorization code here.
- **Authorization code:** A code that the auth server returns to the client which can be exchanged for an access token at the api server.
- **Access Token:** A string that identifies a user, usually comes with an expiry period.
- **Consumer Key or APP_ID:** a public key used by auth server to identify your application.
- **Consumer Secret or APP_SECRET:** a private key which should be kept confidential.

The below terms have nothing to do with OAuth but are used with OAuth to make it more secure.

- **Timestamp:** a string that tells date and time.
- **Nonce:** a number or string which can be used only once.

[image]
source: http://smerity.com/

I will explain the diagram with Facebook login as an example.

Background;
consider you have done the below, before explaining the diagram:

1. You register an app with Facebook developers portal.
2. Facebook provides you two codes, 1) a `secret_key` and 2) an `app_id`
3. You designed a button which says `Login with Facebook`.

Now the diagram:

1. Client requests the API server.
2. API server redirects to login page saying. `To access the data: please login with facebook to access the page`
3. User clicks on the `login with Facbook` button, a new popup `OAuth dialog` opens. asking for facebook username and password.
4. User enters his username and password, then allow access to your app. **auth server** redirects the user to your website with a code as parameter in URL.
5. **API Server** is called on the **step 4**, **API server** captures code from URL.
6. **API server** call **auth server** with the provided `client_secret`
7. **Auth server** returns to the `access token` for the user to the API Server.
8. **API server** asks **auth server** for user information for the given `access token`.
9. **Auth Server** returns details about user, profile pic, email etc.
10. **API server** identifies the user, sends him the response along with access token.
11. **client** sends the access token to the **api server** on next request.
12. **API server** checks if access token is valid and respond.
13. When access token is expired, **client** is asked to login again.

Now, **How does this secure your api?**

Make the portions which need security as login required to access them. if the client who makes the request is not logged in to your api, send him to step 2 of the diagram.

**So what is nonce? timestamp?**

If someone steal an access token, he can get access to **API server** as long as the access token expires. So when the user requests a page, server sends him back a nonce which is stored in the server. the client signs the request with the recieved nonce and complete the request. as the nonce is only used once, server deletes the nonce. when an attacker grabs the nonce, and make a fake request to the server,server rejects the request as the one time number is invalid as its used already.

TimeStamp is used identify the time the token or nonce is created which is used to expire the token or nonce in a limited time frame (1-2seconds), the time needed for a request to complete.

Comment: I have one question about this approach, in terms of security. If the **code** from Facebook is sent to the URL as a parameter, can't some malicious code capture that and use that to authenticate themselves as someone else?

Comment: @Bolboa Any one who can access network packages and logs can capture the code, so use HTTPS. Since the code is generated for a specific user for a specific app (our app), the code can't be used to authenticate any other user to any other app, this is where the secret **App Credentials** are used. Facebook internals ;)

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy Is possible can i use REST API without oAuth?

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy if I am having a REST API which will be consumed only by my frontend clients(browser and mobile), and no third party apps involved. Is the OAuth2.0 the right tool? I know From and Basic authentication is there. But is Social login the only use case of OAuth2.0?